# when does ambiguity arise in multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++

when does ambiguity arise in multiple inheritance?

Comment: Little more details please. Maybe example? etc

Comment: Depends on what's ambiguous. You can have diamond inheritance, with the same base class inherited from more than once. Or you could just have multiple bases with public/protected member variables/functions with the same name, requiring explicit qualification to access.

Comment: This is a venue where you're expected to do a bit more research before you post a question. If questions have clarity the answers will be in such a way that you will get more insight to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

When you have replicated base class in several paths of inheritance and you are trying to cast to it or call its member-function.

```
struct A { };
struct B : A { };
struct C : A { };
struct D : B, C { }; // has replicated A as the base class

D d;
A* a = static_cast<A*>(&d); // oops
```

The problem has several remedies which depend on the context heavily (using virtual base classes, just refine the aforementioned cast, etc.)

More info [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html), especially [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.8).

Answer (score 3):

One famous example of ambiguity in multiple inheritance is the so-called Diamond Problem.

Summary:
"In object-oriented programming languages with multiple inheritance and knowledge organization, the diamond problem is an ambiguity that arises when two classes B and C inherit from A, and class D inherits from both B and C. If a method in D calls a method defined in A (and does not override the method), and B and C have overridden that method differently, then from which class does it inherit: B, or C?"

You can find details here: [Wikipedia: Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Base{
  void foo(){
  }
};

struct Derived1 : public Base{
};

struct Derived2 : public Base{
};

struct Final : public Derived1, public Derived2{
};

int main(){
  Final f;
  f.foo();
}
```

[See on Ideone](http://ideone.com/CQIyS). To fix, simply use virtual inheritance:

```
struct Derived1 : virtual public Base{
};
struct Derived2 : virtual public Base{
};
```

---

Another possibility for ambigouty is the following:

```
struct Base1{
  void foo(){
  }
};

struct Base2{
  void foo(){
  }
};

struct Final : public Base1, public Base2{
};

int main(){
  Final f;
  f.foo();
}
```

Again, on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/3ywGK). To fix, simple make do the following in `Final`:

```
struct Final : public Base1, public Base2{
  using Base1::foo;
  // or
  // using Base2::foo;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When it makes names used unclear

```
class baseX
{
  private:
  void* callA();//will never be ambiguous.
  protected:
  void* callB();
  public:
  void* callC();
}
class baseY
{
  private:
  void* callA();//will never be ambiguous.
  protected:
  void* callB();
  public:
  void* callC();
}
class derived: public baseX, public baseY
{
  void someMethod()
  {
    void* x = baseX::callB();//not ambiguous
    void* y = baseY::callB();//not ambiguous
    void* z = callB();//ambiguose
  }
}
void someFunction(derived& d)
{
  void* x = d.CallC();//ambiguous
}
```

Ambiguity can also happen when the same class is the base through more than one route:

```
class Base
{
  public void call();
}
class DerivedX : public Base
{
}
class DerivedY : public Base
{
}
class GrandChild : public DerivedX, public DerivedY //What does call() do?
{
}
```

This can be solved with virtual bases:

```
class Base
{
  public void call();
}
class DerivedX : public virtual Base
{
}
class DerivedY : public virtual Base
{
}
class GrandChild : public DerivedX, public DerivedY //only one "Base" class in inheritance, shared between DerivedX and DerivedY
{
}
```